# Add new record with conditions not working

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the below code in VB.net to check if ID not exist then to add record in database, the code is not working with condition and add the record without verify if the record already exist or not.
Please advise

```
        rs.MoveFirst()
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            If rs("ID").Value <> TextBox1.Text Then
                rs.AddNew()
                rs("CustomerName").Value = TextBox2.Text
                rs("CustomerAddress").Value = TextBox3.Text
                rs.Update()
            End If
            rs.MoveNext()
        Loop
```

Comment: Please drop this old technology and move to ADO.net.

Comment: Agree with @Mary ... what is datatype of Id Column?? or else try with this ```val(rs("ID").Value.tostring)  <> val(TextBox1.Text)```

Comment: I am still facing same issue

Comment: Just checking, you have got the Tag right.   You are actually using vb.net and not vb6?  If it is vb.net, what Mary said.  On that actual question, remember that string comparisons are case and white space sensitive.  You may need to Trim and force the case on both sides of your comparison.  Or (assuming vb.net) use the String.Equals methods with comparison overloads